# How to export the data in excel and how to upload PHPExcel file into controller using codeiginter?

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

```
I have written the code to export the data into an excel sheet, but the PHPExcel  libray is not loaded into the code.It shows some error while clicking the button"Export".
```

The error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJdM3.png)

```
 public function Arrear_Print(){

    $data['page'] = 'export-excel';
        $data['title'] = 'Export Excel data | TechArise';
        $data['startdate'] =$this->input->post('SDate');
        $data['enddate'] = $this->input->post('EDate');
                $this->load->model('Export');
        $data['PName'] = $this->Export->mobileList();
        // load view file for output
        //$this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('TipUp_Loan\Arrear_Print', $data);
       // $this->load->view('footer');
}
 public function createXLS() {
        // create file name
        $fileName = 'mobile-'.time().'.xlsx';  
        // load excel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $mobiledata = $this->model->Export->mobileList();
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // set Header
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'AcNo');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Mode');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Party Name');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Loan Date');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'Loan Amt');  
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Bal.Amt'); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'Coll.Amt');  
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', 'Rec.Amt');  
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I1', 'Phone.No');
        // set Row
        $rowCount = 2;
        foreach ($mobiledata as $element) 
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $element['TAcNo']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $element['TMode']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $element['TName']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $rowCount, $element['TDate']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $rowCount, $element['TAmt']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $rowCount, $element['total_sum']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G' . $rowCount, $element['RLAmt']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H' . $rowCount, $element['']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I' . $rowCount, $element['Phone']);
            $rowCount++;
        }

        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save($fileName);
        // download file
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
         redirect(site_url().$fileName);              
    }
```

This is a controller code:

```
 <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');


    class Export extends CI_Model {
    // get mobiles list
    public function mobileList() {

        $data['startdate'] =$this->input->post('SDate');
            $data['enddate'] = $this->input->post('EDate');
            $PName  = $this->input->post('TName');
            $SDate  = $this->input->post('SDate');
            $EDate  = $this->input->post('EDate');

            if($PName = $this->input->post('TName')){


            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `TAcNo`,`TMode`,`TDate`,`TAmt`,`TName`, COALESCE(SUM(`RLAmt`) ,0) AS `RLAmt`,`Phone` FROM `tipup_payment`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `tipup_receipt` ON `tipup_receipt`.`TRAcNo` = `tipup_payment`.`TAcNo`  AND `TDate` >= '$SDate' AND `TDate` <= '$EDate' LEFT OUTER JOIN `parmaster` ON `parmaster`.`PName` = `tipup_payment`.`TName`  WHERE TName = '$PName' GROUP BY `TAcNo`ORDER BY `TAcNo` ASC");
               return $query->result_array(); 


            //$data['PName']=$query->result_array();
         //$this->load->view('TipUp_Loan\Arrear_Print',$data,FALSE);
        }

        else {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `TAcNo`,`TMode`,`TDate`,`TAmt`,`TName`, COALESCE(SUM(`RLAmt`) ,0) AS `RLAmt`,`Phone` FROM `tipup_payment` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tipup_receipt` ON `tipup_receipt`.`TRAcNo` = `tipup_payment`.`TAcNo`  AND `TDate` >= '$SDate' AND `TDate` <= '$EDate' LEFT OUTER JOIN `parmaster` ON `parmaster`.`PName` = `tipup_payment`.`TName`  GROUP BY `TAcNo` ORDER BY `TAcNo` ASC");
            return $query->result_array();   
            //$data['PName']=$query->result_array();
          //$this->load->view('TipUp_Loan\Arrear_Print',$data,FALSE);
        }


    }
    }
    ?>
```

This is model code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v2cg.png)
This is input view page....While giving from and to date into the text box.It fetch the data between this date and show it in the view page correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us6mg.png)

This is fetched data and shown in the view page while clicking the "Export" button.The error is displaying that I have never uploaded the picture.

I have downloaded the phpexcel library file in the codeiginter website.

This is link....[enter link description here](https://www.bladephp.co/install-phpexcel-library-in-codeigniter)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The error says that the `PHPExcel.php` file was missing, are you certain the file is there?

Comment: hope you find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580289/data-export-in-excel-using-ci.

Comment: Yes i have set the path

Comment: <?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 
require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/PHPExcel.php";
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?> This is excel.php file in the library

Comment: within `application/third_party` folder, is the file there?

Comment: No sir i didn't create file...

Comment: in that file what i have to mention

Comment: Now i got error like thisFatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Finance\application\libraries\Excel.php on line 12
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Class 'PHPExcel' not found

Filename: libraries/Excel.php

Line Number: 12

Backtrace:

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to solve your problem. It all comes down to how (and where) your PHPExcel files are placed and invoked as from the error message we can assume that PHP is looking for the PHPExcel files in a different location than where they actually are.

YMMV, but this is my installation.

To output a XLS file I get the data arrays from my model (always use `return $query->result_array();` instead of `return $query->result();` in your model unless you want to convert the returned object to array later) and do:

```
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($report);

    $titles = array_keys($data[0]);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($titles, NULL, 'A1');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, NULL, 'A2');

    $filename='output.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Note that I'm calling `$this->excel` which comes from `application/libraries/Excel.php` where this code lives:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/phpexcel/PHPExcel.php";

class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

The core PHPExcel files are, as  you can see from the `require` located on `application/third_party/phpexcel/PHPExcel.php` (always remember to respect case as routes are case-sensitive). On the same level where PHPExcel.php is, I have placed the directory with the core PHPExcel files -including `autoloader.php`-, named PHPExcel.

It's pretty straight-forward and has worked perfectly for me on several projects using CI 3.1.x

Comment: But I have another problem :(

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit further? by re-reading your question, it seems that you're still having trouble to invoke the PHPExcel library correctly.

Comment: You should edit the question then... So far, it still states your problem is related to some variant of `PHPExcel not found`. What problem do you have now?